# Differences in catching touch: UIControl vs UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uicontrol

I have custom class, which has UIView. I want it to do action, when the view is tapped. When i add:

```
[(UIControl*)customClass addTarget:self
                           action:@selector(doAction:) 
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];
```

"doAction" is fireing sometimes when i click the view, however mostly not. But I've noticed that if i add:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doAction:)];
[(UIControl*)customClass addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

What is the difference between these two recognizers? I know, that UIControl has delegates and UIGestureRecognizer, but can't understand why control isn't always catching touch.

The problem is that my sender in case of gestureRecognizer is wrong, because i can't pull some data from it.

```
- (void)doAction:(customClass*)sender {
switch (sender.actionType) { // do something ... } }
```

How to access it? Structure shown in breakpoint is like this:

```
sender -> UIGestureRecognizer -> _view -> _actionType
```